# SchuWeb Sitemap includes Noindex Pages

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, metadata, googlebots

I am using Joomla v3.9.19 along with SchuWeb Sitemaps (v3.1.0).

Recently, I added some new pages (single article menu item) and added in menu entry the metadata `noindex, nofollow`, but SchuWeb Sitemaps still includes these pages.

How can I exclude those pages from the generated Sitemap?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour]. Please continue to research and attempt to self-solve.  If you manage to resolve this issue yourself, it is completely okay to answer your own question.